# Why does my timedata not match the format "'%a %b %d %M: %H: %S %Y'"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a twitter bot that retweets various user's most recent tweets, but my program is having trouble matching the date formats

I have checked the documentation and tried to match the date format exactly, but it does not work, still gives me the error that my timedata doesn't match my format. This is a snippet of the part of my code that is supposed to identify dates

```
def retweet_task(self, screen_name):

    print('Checking for new tweets from @{0}'.format(screen_name))

    timeline = self.api.get_user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name)

    for t in timeline:
        tweet_time = bot.timestr_to_datetime(t['created_at'])

        if tweet_time > self.last_ran:
            print "Retweeting {0}".format(t['id'])
            self.api.retweet(id = t['id'])
```

The program was supposed to find the most recent tweets and retweet them, instead it gives me this error:

```
Checking for new tweets from @realpython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterbot.py", line 49, in <module>
    twitter.retweet_task("realpython")
  File "twitterbot.py", line 31, in retweet_task
    tweet_time = bot.timestr_to_datetime(t['created_at'])
  File "twitterbot.py", line 21, in timestr_to_datetime
    return datetime.strptime(timestr, '%a %b %d %M: %H: %S %Y')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Sun Jul 21 20:01:46 2019' does not match format 
'%a %b %d %M: %H: %S %Y'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've checked the previous threads that had somewhat similar questions but none of those solutions solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timestr` looks like it has hours, minutes, then seconds<sup>1</sup>, separated by colons and no spaces -- i.e. `%H:%M:%S` rather than `%M: %H: %S`  (note carefully the order of the `H` and the `M`):

```
In [170]: import datetime as DT
In [171]: timestr = 'Sun Jul 21 20:01:46 2019'
In [172]: DT.datetime.strptime(timestr, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
Out[172]: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 21, 20, 1, 46)
```

<sup>1</sup>It's possible that `timestr` presents minutes before hours, but the order `%M:%H:%S` would be nonstandard.

Comment: So, I removed the spaces, still get the same error, besides the time changing because of a new tweet, but other than that, removing spaces did nothing.

Comment: Please post the new error message so we can see the value of `timestr`.

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Sun Jul 21 19:44:00 2019' does not match format '%a %b 
    %d %M:%H:%S %Y'